# ipa file size is very large xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am creating single view application with five screen and there is very less images but when I am creating ipa file its size is very large 64mb.I tried some answer ([ans1](http://stackoverflow.hex1.ru/questions/36620229/xcode-7-2-generating-generic-xcode-archive-instead-of-ipa/36620495#36620495),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           [ans2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588757/after-switching-to-xcode-7-app-size-grew-from-9-mb-to-60-mb-is-there-a-fix)) but nothing worked.
I don't have any idea how to reduce ipa file size.

Answer (score 2):

The reason could be in thrird-party libraries if you has them inside your project as a dynamic frameworks. I has a similiar situation when I integrated CocoaReactive & Alamofire & Reachability via Carthage.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Alao there was additional (unused for me) packs for tvOS, watchOS an so on. I deleted them and ipa got smaller size.

Comment: How to delete tvOS and watch OS.

Comment: @SunilSharma what do you use to work with third party libraries? If Carthage there is a the same named folder in you bundle with subfolder Builds where you can find all packs.

Comment: I am not using Carthage.For third party lib I am simply including the source file. I checked for empty project ipa file it is going 43mb.

Comment: I have just created ipa file from just created swift project and it is about  4,6 МБ, so the reason is somewhere inside you project.. Try to check you project folder on more time, there could be some unused content or content with size is more than you think.. It could be icons, spleshimages, sound files, frameworks.. an so on.

Comment: Due to Bitcode Set to enable and dSYM in release mode