# what do libswiftFoundation.dylib and libswiftcore.dylib do?

Tags: swift, swift2

I've build an ipa package from my iOS app project.
After open the .ipa file with `zip`.
I find that here's so many swift support dynamic libraries.

[image]

I want to know what do `libswiftFoundation.dylib` and `libswiftcore.dylib` do?

Comment: `libswiftcore` contains all the Swift functions and data structures. All the others are Swift versions of Obj-C standard libraries, e.g. `NSFoundation`, `UIKit`, `CoreGraphics` etc.

Comment: @Sulthan So swift re-implement those standard libraries instead of wrap them with a bunch of swift interfaces. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

`libSwiftCore` contains Swift standard library functions and structures. The size probably caused by embedded bitcode.

All the other files are the Swift wrappers for Objective-C libraries, e.g. `NSFoundation`, `UIKit` etc. I am surprised by the size of the Foundation wrapper but that's probably the most complex library there.

[After switching to Xcode 7, app size grew from 9 MB to 60 MB, is there a fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588757/after-switching-to-xcode-7-app-size-grew-from-9-mb-to-60-mb-is-there-a-fix) could be connected here.

Answer (score 0):

They are Swift standard libraries. Basically, that comes with swift like arrays, dictionaries etc.