# iOS .app file larger than total Xcode project folder

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, .app, xcode-project

[Contains the terminal .app unzip info](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iSMDPZuiw9YTvuU-KzJ905vgp7fU17-TjRsYnCPIOgI/edit?usp=sharing)I built the iOS app. Total Xcode project size is under 100 MB only. After I built the app, I got the .app build size is nearly 300 MB. Why happen like that. It's also taking a long time (nearly 30 minutes) for build. How can I reduce the size of .app file and how can I make fast compile the application.

Comment: We need more information. Do you use build scripts? Fat Libs? ...?

Comment: Build script means.
I used cocoa pods in application which are also have small sized library.

Comment: Target->Build Script

Comment: I already  some issues of similar types But they are saying that it is happening only in `x-code 8.3`. So which x-code you are using.?

Comment: Im using Xcode 8.2.1

@agent_stack, Did you found any solution?

Comment: @shallowThought, I didnt fine Build Script under Target section.

Comment: @KAREEMMAHAMMED Try with different System after cleaning the derived data otherwise you have to report to Apple thats all I can say.

Comment: Sorry. Its: Target-> Build Phases -> Build Script Phase (exists only if you or pods or someone added it).

Comment: @KAREEMMAHAMMED Can you check your ipa structure and check what is taking so much space? Just rename `app.ipa` to `app.zip` and uncompress it and see the content of folder and package. Also if it's in swift then dylibs can take some of the space.

Comment: @KAREEMMAHAMMED you can read my post similar to this here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/41907323/468724

Comment: @KAREEMMAHAMMED In your terminal your can run `unzip -lv app.ipa` command to see the content and it's size. Then post the output in your question so that we've more idea about your problem

Comment: @InderKumarRathore
i had done the unzip in terminal.
Its a big list come.

Comment: @KAREEMMAHAMMED please put that in a txt file and give it's dropbox/drive link in your question

Comment: @KAREEMMAHAMMED how are you calculating the size of your project? I mean can you show us your directory structure and its size?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore, Yes folder directory structure only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139841/discussion-between-inder-kumar-rathore-and-kareem-mahammed).

Answer (score 2):

Your binary `HealthNotes` is of 155.11 MB which is obviously your code. I couldn't find any suspicious in the app. May be you can find which files are not required by your project. As far as I can see that your ipa size is `107900607` or `102.9MB` see the last lines of your txt file. The `381102989` or `363.44MB` is your uncompressed size.

```
     708  Defl:N      713  -1% 04-03-2017 18:49 e15402ec  HealthNotes.app/Yes_UnCheck.png
    1469  Defl:N     1472  -0% 04-03-2017 18:49 f552f434  HealthNotes.app/Yes_UnCheck@2x.png
--------          -------  ---                            -------
381102989         107900607  72%                            1345 files
```

---

I can see below files file which are large. Do check them if they are required.

```
162649824  Defl:N 36082060  78%  HealthNotes.app/HealthNotes
  1230558  Defl:N  1074344  13%  HealthNotes.app/Cross_Cover.pdf
  9538912  Defl:N  2249073  76%  HealthNotes.app/Frameworks/Charts.framework/Charts
  3377536  Defl:N  1127251  67%  HealthNotes.app/Frameworks/CorePlot.framework/CorePlot
  2775376  Defl:N   727248  74%  HealthNotes.app/Frameworks/CVCalendar.framework/CVCalendar
 61679504  Defl:N 16278564  74%  HealthNotes.app/Frameworks/FHIR.framework/FHIR
 14698896  Defl:N  3921664  73%  HealthNotes.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
  2983440  Defl:N   396294  87%  HealthNotes.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
 64744880  Defl:N 17168102  74%  HealthNotes.app/Frameworks/SMART.framework/SMART
 20873216  Defl:N  7869148  62%  HealthNotes.app/mobilecharts.sqlite
```

### Tips for Reducing app size

1. Use [TinyPng](http://tinypng.com) to compress your images
2. Use image.xcasset so that app store can provide device based assets. Which will reduce the download size of the app.
3. Remove unnecessary images/fonts/html/pdf/sqlite/etc from your project.

Answer (score 0):

The app has lot of files which made the ipa large.

- Reduce Images usage
- Change jpeg to png
- Try decreasing png to small resolution
- Remove unused files
- Load images from web and cache it where possible